# What should I use for about page in models or should I just use it as a template only?

Tags: django-models

```
class About(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

I just need some advice on how I should do this. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use the flatpages app https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/flatpages/

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna do that since the about page is not doing much